# Creation AS400 readable QR Code to scan with Zebra scanner

Tags: ibm-midrange, zebra-printers, zpl

I have searched for an answer for my question, and tested several routes, with no success. So this is my last resort.

The company I work for uses a system running on AS400. We also use Zebra TC520K scanners and ZT400 Printer.

I'm looking for a ZPL code which we can print, that creates a QR Code, with the following details:

```
Line 1: 10 Characters: NAME
Line 2: 10 Characters: PASSWORD
```

Considering the names do not always fill up the line, we need either a Tab or a Line feed.
We have tried several ways of integrating code (Hexadecimal, looking or AS400 code) but no avail.

Is there someone that's able to help us out with this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are having a problem with. Is it the basic syntax of the `^BQ` command, pading the values with spaces up to 10 characters, or putting a new line character between them?

Comment: You shouldn't store plaintext passwords in a QR code (presumably to log into the AS400)

Answer (score 0):

ZPL II QR Code:

Newline:

```
^XA
^FT44,137^BQN,2,4
^FH\^FDLA,NAME\0D\0APASSWORD^FS
^XZ
```

Spaces:

```
^XA
^FT44,137^BQN,2,4
^FH\^FDLA,NAME      PASSWORD  ^FS
^XZ
```

Tab:

```
^XA
^FT44,137^BQN,2,4
^FH\^FDLA,NAME\09PASSWORD^FS
^XZ
```